# I am calling 3 API's from angular, I want to wait API call until first API call is complete and return resu

Tags: angular, angular12

```
if (article[0] === undefined) {
        this.saveArticle(this.quickExpense.ExpenseArticle);
      }

      if (supplier[0] === undefined) {
        this.saveSupplier(this.quickExpense.SupplierCode);
      }
      else{
        this.quickExpense.SupplierCode = supplier[0].value;
      }

      if ((article[0] !== undefined || this.isArticleSaved) && (supplier[0] !== undefined || this.isSupplierSaved)) {
        this.saveQuickExpense(this.quickExpense);
      }
```

Here article and supplier are list variables. I want to post article and supplier if not exists and after execution of these API's I want to assign result to this.quickExpense and then want to call saveQuickExpense. But currently before getting result of article and supplier API saveQuickExpense API is getting called.

Comment: use switchMap or concatMap from rxjs

Comment: Please specify the return values of the save* methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to an observable to make it happen which makes it asynchronous, so you need to understand the difference between synchronous and asynchronous code.

```
console.log(1);
setTimeout(() => {
    Console.log(2);
});
console.log(3);
```

You would expect the output will be 123 but it's actually 132 because the code inside the setTimeout is asynchronous similarly is the case for your api calls, always synchronous code will execute followed by asynchronous code

So just call one api after another inside the subscribe block and this issue will disappear

```
(article[0] === undefined ? this.saveArticle(this.quickExpense.ExpenseArticle) : of({})).subscribe(() =>{ 
     if (supplier[0] === undefined) {
        this.saveSupplier(this.quickExpense.SupplierCode);
      }
      else{
        this.quickExpense.SupplierCode = supplier[0].value;
      }

      if ((article[0] !== undefined || this.isArticleSaved) && (supplier[0] !== undefined || this.isSupplierSaved)) {
        this.saveQuickExpense(this.quickExpense);
      }
      });
```

Answer (score -1):

> use promise and async/await  like
>
> your servicer look like

```
 getCustomMaterialList(payload: any) {
return this.http.post<any>(`${this.apiUrl}/CustomMaterial/GetCustomMaterialList`, payload).toPromise();
```

}

```
  async getData(){
const abc = await this.yourservice.getCustomMaterialList()
 console.log(abc);
}
```

this is only example of async/await

Comment: You shouldn't be using promises in Angular. Use RxJS Observables instead